# 'perf top' command doesn't run properly on virtual machine

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, performancecounter, perf

I got a virtual machine running Ubuntu 12.04 with linux kernel 3.2.0-31. When I try to run the `sudo perf top` command, which can profile the entire system's processes and gather their information, none of the information shows up. But other commands runs fine, like `perf stat ls` that collects all performance info running ls command.

[image: screenshot]

So I am wondering : is that because `perf top` command does not support virtual machine? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this a guest on vmware. Then it will not work.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2015931